# How can I make my Python script for automated Minecraft gameplay more reliable?

Tags: python, performance, minecraft

I wrote the below script to automate Minecraft gameplay, but it occasionally will stop pressing the mouse button down.

Is there any way to make it more reliable?

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
import keyboard
while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed("l"):
        while True:
            pyautogui.mouseDown()
            keyboard.press("w")
            if keyboard.is_pressed("p"):
                quit()
```

Comment: "Optimize" usually means make faster, not make work.

Answer (score 0):

`pyautogui.mouseDown()` never releases the mouse button, so calling it once should hold it down indefinitely.

### If you want to press and hold:

move `pyautogui.mouseDown()` outside the while loop.

```
if keyboard.is_pressed("l"):
    pyautogui.mouseDown()
    while True:
        keyboard.press("w")
        . . .
```

### If you want to click:

use `pyautogui.click()` inside the while loop.

```
if keyboard.is_pressed("l"):
    while True:
        pyautogui.click()
        keyboard.press("w")
        . . .
```

Comment: `while True` can loop millions of time in a second depending on the code within the loop and the speed of the computer being used. Calling `pyautogui.mouseDown()` multiple times (let alone thousands or millions of times) can result in unwanted behavior as you have seen.

Comment: If you want to press and hold, remember to call `pyautogui.mouseUp` somewhere (before `quit()`) to ensure that the mouse button is released.

Comment: hello ty for the help when i tried it it worked but i have 1 big problem now i cant stop the script because the w button gets pressed so many times that i cant stop it